# PyCharm unittests only work individually

Tags: python, unit-testing, pycharm

I can run my test cases individually by right-clicking them and selecting `Run 'Unittests in test_whatever'` but when I right-click the project root folder and select `Run 'Unittests in MyProject'` I get ImportErrors such as this:

```
Testing started at 10:42 ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.5\helpers\pycharm\utrunner.py", line 113, in <module>
    modules = loadModulesFromFolderRec(a[0])
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.5\helpers\pycharm\utrunner.py", line 63, in loadModulesFromFolderRec
    os.path.walk(folder, walkModules, (modules, pattern))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 272, in walk
    walk(name, func, arg)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 272, in walk
    walk(name, func, arg)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 272, in walk
    walk(name, func, arg)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 272, in walk
    walk(name, func, arg)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 272, in walk
    walk(name, func, arg)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 272, in walk
    walk(name, func, arg)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 272, in walk
    walk(name, func, arg)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 268, in walk
    func(arg, top, names)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.5\helpers\pycharm\utrunner.py", line 51, in walkModules
    modules.append(loadSource(os.path.join(dirname, name)))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.5\helpers\pycharm\utrunner.py", line 40, in loadSource
    module = imp.load_source(moduleName, fileName)
  File "C:\Users\Filip\PycharmProjects\MyProject\venv\lib\python2.7\site-packages\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_AES.py", line 29, in <module>
    from common import dict     # For compatibility with Python 2.1 and 2.2
ImportError: No module named common
```

I'm assuming this has something to do with the working directory.

I'm running python 2.7.9. And yes, the virtualenv is in the project folder, and on git. Don't ask.

Comment: paste your settings file

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the checkboxes *Add content roots to PYTHONPATH* and *Add source roots to PYTHONPATH* in the *Run/Debug Configuration* Dialog of pyCharm. If not, this could help.